# How to merge 2 cells to generate a new value/text in an empty column cell?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns: firstName, lastName and emailAddress

firstName and lastName are populated with values but emailAddress column is empty. How do I generate and insert an email address for each person by combining their first and last names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the rows are already inserted  the you could use update

assuming that email Address is based on a pattern like `firstName.lastName@domain.country`

```
update my_table  
set emailAddress = concat(firstName, '.',lastName,'@', 'yourdomanin.xyz')
;
```